# Terraform Azure VM extension type and type_handler_version parameter values for AADLoginForWindows

Tags: azure, terraform

I'm trying to add the AADLoginForWindows VM extension to an Azure Windows Server VM using version 1.21.0 of the terraform azurerm provider.

The install fails with the message:

```
Failure sending request: StatusCode=404 -- Original Error: Code="ArtifactNotFound" Message="Extension with publisher 'Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory', type 'AADLoginForWindows', and type handler version '1.0' could not be found in the extension repository.
```

The Terraform config to apply AADLoginForLinux (which works):

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "AADLoginForLinux" {
    name                              = "AADLoginForLinux"
    location                          = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.vm-linux-bastion.location}"
    resource_group_name               = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.vm-linux-bastion.resource_group_name}"
    virtual_machine_name              = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.vm-linux-bastion.name}"
    publisher                         = "Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.LinuxSSH"
    type                              = "AADLoginForLinux"
    type_handler_version              = "1.0"
    auto_upgrade_minor_version        = true
}
```

I suspect there is something wrong with either the type or type_handler_version parameter values but I don't understand what these values relate to (and some Googling has not provided enlightenment).

There is no documentation available for AADLoginForWindows (perhaps that should be a warning! ;) ) but I'm hoping that it works much the same way as AADLoginForLinux, which allows us to log in to Linux VMs using credentials managed directly in Azure AD.

My Terraform configuration is:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "AADLoginForWindows" {
    name                              = "AADLoginForWindows"
    location                          = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg-dataaq-prd-neu-ftps.location}"
    resource_group_name               = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg-dataaq-prd-neu-ftps.name}"
    virtual_machine_name              = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.vm-windows.name}"
    publisher                         = "Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory"
    type                              = "AADLoginForWindows"
    type_handler_version              = "1.0"
    auto_upgrade_minor_version        = true
    depends_on                     = ["azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.antimal"]
}
```

Using the `az cli` I can find the following info about versions of the extension:

```
az vm extension image list --name AADLoginForWindows
[
  {
    "name": "AADLoginForWindows",
    "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory",
    "version": "0.3.0.0"
  },
  {
    "name": "AADLoginForWindows",
    "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory",
    "version": "0.3.1.0"
  }
]
```

Inquiring about a specific version of the extension:

```
az vm extension image show --name AADLoginForWindows --publisher "Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory" --location northeurope --version "0.3.1.0"
{
  "computeRole": "IaaS",
  "handlerSchema": null,
  "id": "/Subscriptions/.../Providers/Microsoft.Compute/Locations/northeurope/Publishers/Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory/ArtifactTypes/VMExtension/Types/AADLoginForWindows/Versions/0.3.1.0",
  "location": "northeurope",
  "name": "0.3.1.0",
  "operatingSystem": "Windows",
  "supportsMultipleExtensions": false,
  "tags": null,
  "type": null,
  "vmScaleSetEnabled": false
}
```

I think the "publisher" Terraform parameter must equate to the publisher value in the first query.

The fact that type comes back as null in the second query makes me wonder if that really does map to the "type" Terraform param.

There doesn't seem to be anything related to a type_handler_version.

Does anyone know what config I should be using to get this VM extension installed?

Can anyone describe the Terraform type and type_handler_version parameters in a bit more detail (and describe how to find valid values)?

To test whether this is a Terraform bug I tried applying the extension using the `az cli` tool:

```
az vm extension set -n AADLoginForWindows --publisher "Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory" --vm vmname --resource-group rg-name
```

This gives the below error:

```
Handler 'Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.AADLoginForWindows' has reported failure for VM Extension 'AADLoginForWindows' with terminal error code '1007' and error message: 'Install failed for plugin (name: Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.AADLoginForWindows, version 0.3.1.0) with exception Command C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.AADLoginForWindows\0.3.1.0\AADLoginForWindowsHandler.exe of Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.AADLoginForWindows has exited with Exit code: 51'
```

Comment: did you get this working?

Answer (score 1):

change your type_handler_version to match the actual one (0.3.1.0 according to your findings)

```
type_handler_version              = "0.3.1.0"
```

it cannot downgrade the version, only upgrade, and only minor version.

Linux version works because (so its higher than 1.0.0.0):
[image]

While windows version is still not on 1.0:
[image]

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work, the error message is now: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="InvalidParameter" Message="The value of parameter typeHandlerVersion is invalid." Target="typeHandlerVersion", which makes me think that the "type handler" that is versioned is not the same thing as the actual extension I'm trying to apply...

Comment: this looks like yet another bug in shittyform. because I'm quite sure about this error and about how to fix it

Comment: I dont think so, I've edited my question to show a working terraform configuration to apply the equivalent VM extension for a linux VM.

Comment: You may well be correct about a bug in terraform around versions under 1.x however to check I just had a go applying the extension using az (see update in question above), that also failed so I suspect this extension is fundamentally broken...

Comment: that might be the case, didnt really use that extension, but that particular error is pretty clear, you need to use proper version, and that what I'm showing is how its supposed to be ;)

Answer (score 1):

May be a bit late to the party, but the issue is still ongoing.  I managed to successfully deploy the extension to a Windows Server 2019 VM using `type_handler_version = "1.0"`

Answer (score 1):

## The version of azure_rm that i am using is ***> 2.50 and terraform > 1.0***

1. First! your Virtual Machine is windows so use the login from windows.
2. Second! the virtual machine must be sent as the id
3. Third! the resource group is not needed

The correct extension and code are:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "example" {
  name                 = "AADLoginForWindows"
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.example.id
  type                       = "AADLoginForWindows"
  type_handler_version       = "1.0"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = true
  publisher                         = "Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory"

}
```

Comment: In my case it was an incorrect publisher. It's important to set it as Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory

Answer (score 0):

I quickly gave up trying to get the resource to work. Instead i just used a gross workaround of calling a local provisioner and adding the extension through the AZ Cli

```
provisioner "local-exec" {
  command = "az vm extension set --publisher Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory --name AADLoginForWindows --resource-group ${azurerm_resource_group.managementRG.name} --vm-name myWinVm"
}
```

The provisioner block is inside my `azurerm_virtual_machine` resource. I may take another look at getting it to work properly at some point, but this gets the issue unblocked for now.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code with AzureRM 2.x and Terraform v0.12.x to add the AD login for Linux:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "ad-extenstion-linux" {
  depends_on=[azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.ubuntu-linux-vm]

  name                       = "AADLoginForLinux"
  publisher                  = "Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.LinuxSSH"
  type                       = "AADLoginForLinux"
  type_handler_version       = "1.0"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = true
  virtual_machine_id         = azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.ubuntu-linux-vm.id
}
```